# How to disable ES6 features in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

found very strange and not obvious behavior of javascript in Chrome and maybe all other modern browsers.
Assume we have Html with javascript like this

```
<html>
<title>
</title>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var me = {
            func1: function(){
                console.log('Im function 1');
            },
            func2(){
                console.log('Im function 2');
            }
        };
        me.func1();
        me.func2();

    </script>
</body>
```

When you run this in chrome you will see in console:

```
Im function 1
Im function 2
```

But when you run this in IE11 you will get an error

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
JavascriptTest.html (11,10)
```

As I understand it is not required in ES6 to declare functions as func1, chrome as well happy with declaration like func2

```
var me = {
                func1: function(){
                    console.log('Im function 1');
                },
                func2(){
                    console.log('Im function 2');
                }
            };
```

but for IE11 it is matter. And it is common mistake when you write code on server and client side.
I looking for a way to disable such feature in chrome, is it possible?

Comment: better to use the `transpiler` like babel others to convert the code from ES6 to lower which can be understood by other older browser as well,  it will convert your code to old Javascript code at compile(better) / run time,

Comment: This is why it's important to test thoroughly in your target browsers. :-)

Comment: It's not a common mistake. The one should always be aware of the features he/she uses. Method shortcut is ES6, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015 . It's not possible to do anything like that. Instead, you may incorporate a linter into your project. Of course, this means that code should be more organized and not just reside in inline <script> tags.

Comment: 100% agree with @DeepakSharma, run your stuff through a transpiler rather than disable ES6 in Chrome.  I don't think that's even possible since you'd have to disable features of the JS engine in Chrome at that point.

Comment: @estus: I had to work on a project limited to ES5 features recently. It's **hugely** difficult to unlearn `const`, arrow functions, method declarations, etc., etc., etc. and write ES5 code, once you've been liberated from it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very true. I still use an arrow in ES5 mechanically sometimes and wonder why there's a syntax error.

Comment: I currently run my projects through Babel to transpile down to ES5, but some features require plugins and it'd be great to catch any issues in my Chrome/Puppeteer tests by disabling ES2015+ features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't disable ES2015+ language features in Chrome, no.

What you can do is use a "linter" tool (like ESLint) to check your code to make sure it doesn't have things in it that you don't want. That particular one, for instance, has a [`ecmaVersion` setting](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) that you can use to control what syntax it should and shouldn't allow in your files; presumably others have as well.

Another option (and my preference for my own work) is to use the new features even when my target browser doesn't support them, and *transpile* back to ES5 (in my case, with [Babel](http://babeljs.io)). That way, I get the advantages of the new features, even when I have to support IE.

Comment: Not really helped me, but hopefully will be useful for most searchers